Node.js not sending response
I am writing a small node.js application. The route I use to register users gets stuck in a back end function called emithook when it sends a response object back to the client. I am using visual studio 2022 community edition.
Here is my registration route code.
    registrationRoute.post('/register', async function (req, res) { 
        try {
        
            await mongoose.connect(uri);
            const { username, password, company } = req.body;
            const existingUser = await User.findOne({ userName : username  });
            if (existingUser) {
         
                return res.send({ error: "User Name already Taken" });
            }
        

            const newUser = new User({
                userName : username,
                password: password,
                company: company
        })
            await newUser.save();
            console.log("user successfully registered")
            token = generateToken(newUser.userName)
            return res.status(200).json({token})
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
            return res.status(500).json("unable to register user")
        }
    })

It will get hung up when it encounters an res object.
Here is the back end function it gets hung up in.
function emitHook(symbol, asyncId) {
  active_hooks.call_depth += 1;
  // Use a single try/catch for all hook to avoid setting up one per
  // iteration.
  try {
    // Using var here instead of let because "for (var ...)" is faster than let.
    // Refs: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/30380#issuecomment-552948364
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
    for (var i = 0; i < active_hooks.array.length; i++) {
      if (typeof active_hooks.array[i][symbol] === 'function') {
        active_hooks.array[i][symbol](asyncId);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    fatalError(e);
  } finally {
    active_hooks.call_depth -= 1;
  }

  // Hooks can only be restored if there have been no recursive hook calls.
  // Also the active hooks do not need to be restored if enable()/disable()
  // weren't called during hook execution, in which case
  // active_hooks.tmp_array will be null.
  if (active_hooks.call_depth === 0 && active_hooks.tmp_array !== null) {
    restoreActiveHooks();
  }
}

I have tried removing the return statements from in front of the res objects. Even if I comment out the res objects it still gets hung up in emithook.
I have tried adding:
"skipFiles": \[ "\<node_internals\>/\*\*" \]
to my debug environment.
I would expect this code to work and return the response objects to the client.
Maybe there is something wrong with my promise statements? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I wrote the following mcve. Here is the client code:
    try{
    var res = await fetch('/newInvoice',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: "sending to server" }) 
        })
    if (res.ok) {
        document.getElementById("invoiceCreatedMessage").innerHTML = "Invoice Successfully created"
    }
}catch(err) {
    console.log("there was an error: ", err);
}

})
here is the route code:
newInvoiceRoute.post('/newInvoice', function (req, res) {
    res.send({"message": "sending to client"});

})
The client never receives of never resolves the response. None of the actions that are after the await fetch block are ever hit. I can see in the chrome dev tools that the route is sent. The response shows "Failed to load response data: No resource with given identifier found". I added cors but that did not help.

The question lacks clear problem statement. emitHook isn't something widely known, and it looks like it's stuck during debugging session in vsc? The question makes it look like this happens in production

Apologies, this issue occurs during debug and during production. The server seems to get stuck in some node back end code ("emithook") and never returns an res object to the client.

Can you clarify what is going on? It's unclear how you knew in prod about emitHook. Did it occur to you only when you tried to debug? " hung up when it encounters an res object" - how do you know that? You describe the problem like it's usual but it isn't. You need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it, currently only you're able to reproduce the problem, it needs to be isolated on your side.  You don't need return res in express middlewares but it shouldn't affect the way it works. Since the only async operations are  db, I'd expect a query is pending, probably because of bad connect

Sorry, I am pretty new to asking questions here. I don't know that, in production, the server side code is getting hung up on an res object. It simply never returns anything to the client. I will work on isolating it on my side and getting a minimally reproducible example.

Unless you were able to precisely debug the problem to "res", you can be pretty much sure it's mongoose to blame, it's known to produce pending promises when there's no connection. There's actually nothing to break at all in this middleware without async db calls, especially because you handle errors
